# How to get a different print statement after a certain amount of answers

Tags: java

After three invalid entries I need the 3rd time to display something different and revert back to the first loop. Also am not sure how to make this continuous

```
    do{
    System.out.print("Enter Rating(-1 to quit): ");
    rating = input.nextInt();
    }
    while (rating == 0 || rating == 1 || rating == 2 || rating == 3 || rating == 4);
     System.out.print("Invalid entry. Please enter a whole number "
     + "or enter -1 to quit: ");
    rating = input.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while (rating < 0 || rating > 4)`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean this?

```
/**
   <P>{@code java Test}</P>
 **/
public class Test  {
   public static final void main(String[] ignored)  {
     int iterationCount = 5;
     for(int i = 0; i < iterationCount; i++)  {
          if(i == 2)  {  //Index of 3 is 2
             System.out.println("Printing something special on the third iteration!");
             //You could set i back to 0 here, if that's what you want...
          }  else  {
              System.out.println("Index " + i);
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[C:\java_code\]java Test
Index 0
Index 1
Printing something special on the third iteration!
Index 3
Index 4
```

Comment: @user3344218: If you found this answer helpful, please consider up-voting it and accepting it, by clicking on the big green checkmark. Best of luck!